# How to specify Watson Language Translator service as declared service

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, ibm-watson, node-red

I have a small issue.. I am trying to use the 'deploy to bluemix' button with a node-red application. That is working fine. I also want to deploy two services automatically with this button. For one service it is working, the other will not deploy... This is my manifest file:

```
applications:
    - path: .
      memory: 512M
  instances: 1
  name: LanguageTranslatorLT
  host: LanguageTranslatorLT
  disk_quota: 1024M
- services:
  - LanguageTranslatorLT-cloudantNoSQLDB
  - language-translator-service
  name: language-translator-demo
  env:
      NODE_RED_STORAGE_NAME: LanguageTranslatorLT-cloudantNoSQLDB
declared-services:
  LanguageTranslatorLT-cloudantNoSQLDB:
    label: cloudantNoSQLDB
    plan: Lite
  language-translator-service:
    label: language-translator
    plan: advanced
```

The language-translator-service, will not deploy. when I use the button, I get this error:

```
Binding service LanguageTranslatorLT-cloudantNoSQLDB to app LanguageTranslatorHB-1485255424408-hansb-1633 in org xxx / space dev2 as xxx...
OK
FAILED
Could not find service LanguageTranslatorLT-LanguageTranslator to bind to LanguageTranslatorHB-1485255424408-hansb-1633

Finished: FAILED
```

I guess it is something in the naming of the service, but I cannot find it. Maybe someone else knows?

Answer (score 0):

When running `cf marketplace` the Language Translator service is listed as:
`language_translator` (with underscore instead of dash) with standard, advanced and premium plans.

In your manifest file you need to correct the section to:

```
  language-translator-service:
    label: language_translator
    plan: advanced
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that for language translator the label you need to use is language_translator. IE.

`declared-services:
  LanguageTranslatorLT-cloudantNoSQLDB:
    label: cloudantNoSQLDB
    plan: Lite
  language-translator-service:
    label: language_translator
    plan: advanced`

You can tell what services are available to you by running the command

`cf marketplace`

as described in the documentation for creating your own deploy button. - https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/develop/deploy_button.html